# How to display error message if value of a field is missing and user starts typing for the next field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

Eg- If the user starts typing the password but has not entered email yet instantly display the message - “Enter Email Id First”.
I am using bootstrap4 & jQuery/Javascript.The cursor should reach that field where error is found.Along with that when all the validations are met, how do I redirect to another page when I click the Submit Button. I have tried using anchor tags in HTML for redirection on click of the button which obviously results in redirecting to the link rather than checking validations. I have tried using window.location method but it doesn't give any response.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Three Forms</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color : grey">
  <div class="container" style="background-color:  green;padding-bottom: 2%;">
    <div style="background-color:black;">
      <h2><b>Forms</b></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:3%;">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="background-color:white;padding:0px;margin-left: 4%;margin-right: 3%;margin-bottom:3%;">
        <form class="form-A" id="form-A">
          <div style="background: linear-gradient(to top left, #ff9999 0%, #ff9966 35%); height: 100px; text-align : center;     color:white;">
            <h3><b>Log In</b></h3>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="color:white;"></i></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter" style="color:white;"></i></a>
            <a href="https://plus.google.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" style="color:white;"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div style="padding: 4%;">

            <div class="form-sm">
              <input type="Email" id="email1" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Your Email">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-2"></div>
            <div class="form-sm">
              <input type="Password" id="password1" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Your Password">
            </div>
            <div class="text-right mt-4">
              <a class="btn btn-link" href="https://www.google.com" style="color:grey;font-size:normal;">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
            <div class="text-left mt-4" style="font-size:8px;font-weight: normal;">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" id="login" style="Background-color:grey; border-radius:25px;" onclick="return     form1validations() ">
   Log In<i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button> &nbsp;
              <span style="color:grey;">Don't have an account?</span>
              <a class="btn btn-link" href="Sign Up" style="text-align : Right;color:black; font-size:10px;">Sign up?</a>
            </div>
            <div class="pb-4"></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>


      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="background-color:white;padding:0px;margin-left:4%;margin-right:3%;margin-bottom:3%;">
        <form id="form-B" style="padding-left:4%;padding-right:3%;margin-left:-4%;margin-right:-3%;">
          <h3 style="color:#cc00cc;text-align : center;"><b>Sign Up</b></h3>
          <div class="md-form form-sm" style="padding: 3%;">
            <div class="mb-5"></div>
            <input type="Email" id="email2" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Your Email">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-2"></div>
          <div class="md-form form-sm" style="padding: 3%;margin-top:-6%">
            <input type="Password" id="password2" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Your Password">
          </div>
          <div class="text-left mt-4" style="color:grey;font-size:15px;font-weight: normal;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" style="color:grey;font-size:15px;font-weight: normal;"> Accept the<a href="https://amazon.com">Terms and Conditions</a>
          </div>
          <div class="text-left mt-4" style="font-size:9px;font-weight: normal;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="signup" style="background-color : DeepPink;border-radius:25px;" onclick="return     form2validations()">Sign Up
   <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
            <span style="color:grey;">have an account?</span>
            <a class="btn btn-link" href="Log In" style="text-align : Right; font-size:9px;">Log In?</a>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-4"></div>
          <div style="background: linear-gradient(to top, #666699 100%, #666699 0%); height: 100px; text-align : center;     color:white;"><br><br>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="color:white;"></i> 
   </a><a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter" style="color:white;"></i></a>
            <a href="https://plus.google.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" style="color:white;"></i></a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="background-color:white;margin-left: 4%;margin-right:3%;padding:top:0.5%;margin-bottom:3%; ">
        <form id="form-C">
          <h3 style="text-align : center;"><b>Sign In </b></h3>
          <div class="md-form form-sm" style="padding-top:1%;">
            <div class="mb-5"></div>
            <input type="Email" id="email3" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Your Email">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-2"></div>
          <div class="md-form form-sm">
            <input type="Password" id="password3" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Your Password">
          </div>
          <div class="text-right mt-4">
            <a class="btn btn-link" href="https://www.gmail.com">Forgot Password?</a>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center p-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="signin" style="width : 85%;border-radius:25px;" onclick="return     form3validations()">Sign In
   <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i>
   </button>
          </div>
          <div style="color:grey;text-align : center;font-size:15px;">or sign in with:</div>
          <div class="mb-2"></div>
          <div style="text-align:center;color:Blue;">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="btn btn-link" style="background-color: lightgrey;width:15%;
   border-radius:25%;" role="button">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com" class="btn btn-link" style="background-color:lightgrey;width:15%;
   border-radius:25%;" role="button">
              <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.plus.google.com" class="btn btn-link" style="background-color: lightgrey;width:15%;
   border-radius:25%;" role="button"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3"></div>

    <script>
      function form1validations() {
        var email1 = document.getElementById("email1").value;
        var password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
        var mail1 = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
        var pswd1 = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/;
        if (email1.length == 0) {
          alert('email cannot be empty!');
          return;
        } else if (!email1.match(mail1)) {
          return;
        } else if (password1.length == 0) {
          alert('password cannot be empty!');
          return false;
        } else if (!password1.match(pswd1)) {
          alert('password is incorrect!')
          return false;
        } else {
          alert('you are sucessfully Logged in!');
        }
        window.location.href = "/home/user/Shivam/newpage.html";
      }

      function form2validations() {
        var email2 = document.getElementById("email2").value;
        var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
        var mail2 = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
        var pswd2 = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/;
        if (email2.length == 0) {
          alert('email cannot be empty!');
          return;
        } else if (!email2.match(mail2)) {
          return;
        } else if (password2.length == 0) {
          alert('password cannot be empty!');
          return false;
        } else if (!password2.match(pswd2)) {
          alert('password is incorrect!')
          return false;
        } else if (!document.getElementById('checkbox').checked) {
          alert('Checkbox not checked');
          return false;
        } else {
          alert('Sign Up successful!');
        }

        window.location.href = "/home/user/Shivam/newpage.html";
      }

      function form3validations() {
        var email3 = document.getElementById("email3").value;
        var password3 = document.getElementById("password3").value;
        var mail3 = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
        var pswd3 = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/;
        if (email3.length == 0) {
          alert('email cannot be empty!');
          return;
        } else if (!email3.match(mail3)) {
          return;
        } else if (password3.length == 0) {
          alert('password cannot be empty!');
          return false;
        } else if (!password3.match(pswd3)) {
          alert('password is incorrect!')
          return false;
        } else {
          alert('you are sucessfully Signed In!');
        }
        window.location.href = "/home/user/Shivam/newpage.html";
      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are using jquery better to use jquery validation library it will give you a better way to write all the way of validation and fill your requirement.
 
https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: With bootstrap you can (should use) follow their guidelines for validation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation It relies on html5 form validation mechanism, that you can further refine if needed. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below snippet where I have added validations when you focus on input field. Works fine check for form1. I had to remove the focus in your validation function else it will get stuck in loop. Also I suggest you create separate validation when input is focussed and when form is submitted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Three Forms</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color : grey">
  <div class="container" style="background-color:  green;padding-bottom: 2%;">
    <div style="background-color:black;">
      <h2><b>Forms</b></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:3%;">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="background-color:white;padding:0px;margin-left: 4%;margin-right: 3%;margin-bottom:3%;">
        <form class="form-A" id="form-A">
          <div style="background: linear-gradient(to top left, #ff9999 0%, #ff9966 35%); height: 100px; text-align : center;     color:white;">
            <h3><b>Log In</b></h3>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="color:white;"></i></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter" style="color:white;"></i></a>
            <a href="https://plus.google.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" style="color:white;"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div style="padding: 4%;">

            <div class="form-sm">
              <input type="Email" id="email1" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Your Email">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-2"></div>
            <div class="form-sm">
              <input onfocus="form1validations()" type="Password" id="password1" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Your Password">
            </div>
            <div class="text-right mt-4">
              <a class="btn btn-link" href="https://www.google.com" style="color:grey;font-size:normal;">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
            <div class="text-left mt-4" style="font-size:8px;font-weight: normal;">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" id="login" style="Background-color:grey; border-radius:25px;" onclick="return     form1validations() ">
   Log In<i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button> &nbsp;
              <span style="color:grey;">Don't have an account?</span>
              <a class="btn btn-link" href="Sign Up" style="text-align : Right;color:black; font-size:10px;">Sign up?</a>
            </div>
            <div class="pb-4"></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>


      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="background-color:white;padding:0px;margin-left:4%;margin-right:3%;margin-bottom:3%;">
        <form id="form-B" style="padding-left:4%;padding-right:3%;margin-left:-4%;margin-right:-3%;">
          <h3 style="color:#cc00cc;text-align : center;"><b>Sign Up</b></h3>
          <div class="md-form form-sm" style="padding: 3%;">
            <div class="mb-5"></div>
            <input type="Email" id="email2" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Your Email">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-2"></div>
          <div class="md-form form-sm" style="padding: 3%;margin-top:-6%">
            <input type="Password" id="password2" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Your Password">
          </div>
          <div class="text-left mt-4" style="color:grey;font-size:15px;font-weight: normal;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" style="color:grey;font-size:15px;font-weight: normal;"> Accept the<a href="https://amazon.com">Terms and Conditions</a>
          </div>
          <div class="text-left mt-4" style="font-size:9px;font-weight: normal;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="signup" style="background-color : DeepPink;border-radius:25px;" onclick="return     form2validations()">Sign Up
   <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
            <span style="color:grey;">have an account?</span>
            <a class="btn btn-link" href="Log In" style="text-align : Right; font-size:9px;">Log In?</a>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-4"></div>
          <div style="background: linear-gradient(to top, #666699 100%, #666699 0%); height: 100px; text-align : center;     color:white;"><br><br>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="color:white;"></i> 
   </a><a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter" style="color:white;"></i></a>
            <a href="https://plus.google.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" style="color:white;"></i></a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="background-color:white;margin-left: 4%;margin-right:3%;padding:top:0.5%;margin-bottom:3%; ">
        <form id="form-C">
          <h3 style="text-align : center;"><b>Sign In </b></h3>
          <div class="md-form form-sm" style="padding-top:1%;">
            <div class="mb-5"></div>
            <input type="Email" id="email3" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Your Email">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-2"></div>
          <div class="md-form form-sm">
            <input type="Password" id="password3" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Your Password">
          </div>
          <div class="text-right mt-4">
            <a class="btn btn-link" href="https://www.gmail.com">Forgot Password?</a>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center p-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="signin" style="width : 85%;border-radius:25px;" onclick="return     form3validations()">Sign In
   <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i>
   </button>
          </div>
          <div style="color:grey;text-align : center;font-size:15px;">or sign in with:</div>
          <div class="mb-2"></div>
          <div style="text-align:center;color:Blue;">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="btn btn-link" style="background-color: lightgrey;width:15%;
   border-radius:25%;" role="button">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com" class="btn btn-link" style="background-color:lightgrey;width:15%;
   border-radius:25%;" role="button">
              <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.plus.google.com" class="btn btn-link" style="background-color: lightgrey;width:15%;
   border-radius:25%;" role="button"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3"></div>

    <script>
      function form1validations() {
        var email1 = document.getElementById("email1").value;
        var password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
        var mail1 = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
        var pswd1 = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/;
        if (email1.length == 0) {
          document.getElementById("password1").blur();
          document.getElementById("email1").focus();
          alert('email cannot be empty!');
          return;
        } else if (!email1.match(mail1)) {
          return;
        }
      }

      function form2validations() {
        var email2 = document.getElementById("email2").value;
        var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
        var mail2 = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
        var pswd2 = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/;
        if (email2.length == 0) {
          alert('email cannot be empty!');
          return;
        } else if (!email2.match(mail2)) {
          return;
        } else if (password2.length == 0) {
          alert('password cannot be empty!');
          return false;
        } else if (!password2.match(pswd2)) {
          alert('password is incorrect!')
          return false;
        } else if (!document.getElementById('checkbox').checked) {
          alert('Checkbox not checked');
          return false;
        } else {
          alert('Sign Up successful!');
        }

        window.location.href = "/home/user/Shivam/newpage.html";
      }

      function form3validations() {
        var email3 = document.getElementById("email3").value;
        var password3 = document.getElementById("password3").value;
        var mail3 = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
        var pswd3 = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/;
        if (email3.length == 0) {
          alert('email cannot be empty!');
          return;
        } else if (!email3.match(mail3)) {
          return;
        } else if (password3.length == 0) {
          alert('password cannot be empty!');
          return false;
        } else if (!password3.match(pswd3)) {
          alert('password is incorrect!')
          return false;
        } else {
          alert('you are sucessfully Signed In!');
        }
        window.location.href = "/home/user/Shivam/newpage.html";
      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Although I need to check password as well. Now how do I unblur it when email is entered? The popup doesn't go away.

Comment: and I also need the cursor to reach the emailbox

Comment: updated for cursor to reach email box. To get rid of pop click on ok in alert box. For checking password create a separate validator.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple form for you that does the work.

I have used [`Element.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) method to show the user which field is required.

```js
let checkFill = el => {
  let siblings = [...el.parentNode.children];
  let bool = true;
  
  if(siblings.indexOf(el) !== 0) {
    for(let s of siblings) {
      if(s !== el) {
        if(s.value.length === 0) {
          alert('Fill out the previous fields first!');
          window.scrollTo(0, s.offsetTop);
          s.focus();
          bool = false;
          break;
        }
      } else break;
    }
  }
  
  return bool;
};

let redirect = bool => {
  if(bool) {
    window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
    console.log(window.location.href);
  }
};
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 75vw;
  margin: 20vh auto;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

button {
  height: 80px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10vh;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='email' onFocus='checkFill(this);' required/>
  <input type='password' onFocus='checkFill(this);' required/>
  <input type='number' onFocus='checkFill(this);' required/>
  <button id='btn' onClick='redirect(checkFill(this));'>Log In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! your code works well but I don't know how to apply it in my own form and js validations. Can you help me?